# trying to understand non-blocking?

Tags: design-patterns, architecture

I have been doing some research and understand that a non-blocking method is a method that will not hold back it's calling thread if it takes too long to return - in other words, it will return something immediately. So, if it does not have something to return, what does it return?

Comment: Nothing. As an example, in C++: `void f() { return; }`.

Comment: will that not break the calling thread? or does the caller prepare for a null return? And how can it be void if usally it does get / expect a return

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So, if it does not have something to return, what does it return?

Nothing. A function can return nothing in almost all the languages.
As an example, in C++ `void f() { return; }` is a valid definition for a function.

---

Anyway, usually those kind of functions are seen in processes where callbacks are usually the way to go.
As an example, `libuv` is a C library that is almost entirely based on callbacks.
In this case, you usually pass a *callback* object (what that object is mostly depends on the language, as an example it can be a function pointer (C), a *lambda function* or a *functor* (C++), an instance of `Function` (JS) or whatever.
This way, the invoked method can freely start asynchronous operations and call back to the caller once finished by means of the callbacks.

---

As a more concrete example, imagine you want to make an http request.
You can do a blocking call that stops the execution of the calling thread until a response arrives and then it returns the data as a return value of the function you invoked to do that call.
Otherwise, you can design a function that accepts a callback, starts the http call and returns. Your callback will be invoked asynchronously whenever a response is received.

Comment: Surely that is still blocking as the async still waits as a callback (calls after received data)?

Comment: It is still, non-blocking, because while the called function (thread) is still running, the caller (thread) is free to do something else, instead of waiting for the called function (thread) to finish (blocking). That is essentially what non-blocking means.

Answer (score 1):

In general in Non-blocking pattern a handler (maybe a function or event) is used to communicate between caller and callee. When caller makes a non blocking call it either pass that handler or have already shared it with callee. The callee immediately returns some status like in progress or maybe null. Whenever callee finishes that work it calls handler with status and caller come to know about the progress through that.

Answer (score 1):

A non-blocking method will either accept a callback, or fire an event, or return a "future", or use some other async continuation mechanism (e.g. `async`/`await` in C#6).

So, you might have:

```
void Process(Action<Data> whenFinishedInvokeThis)
{
    Task.Run(() => 
    {
         var data = DoSomeLongCalculation();
         whenFinishedInvokeThis(data);
    });
}
```

Or:

```
public event Action<Data> Finished;
void Process()
{
    Task.Run(() => 
    {
         var data = DoSomeLongCalculation();
         Finished?.Invoke(data);
    });
}
```

Or:

```
Task<Data> Process()
{
    return Task.Run(DoSomeLongCalculation);
}
```

Or:

```
async Task<Data> Process() 
{
    return await Task.Run(DoSomeLongCalculation);
}
```